# Переменные препроцессора Си

Tags: c, препроцессор

Как подсчитать количество вызовов некоторого макроса препроцессором ?
К примеру, есть макрос

```
#define BLOCK \
<increment preprocessor variable> \
printf("This is a BLOCK № %d\n", <preprocessor variable>);
```

Тогда такой вызов

```
void main(){
    --- some lines of code --
    BLOCK
    --- some lines of code --
    BLOCK
    --- some lines of code --
}
```

Должен вывести

```
This is a BLOCK № 1
This is a BLOCK № 2
```

Вопрос в том как сделать так что бы переменная была именно не в коде программы, а именно переменной препроцессора. Т.е. как с дефайном, но что бы его можно было переписывать.

Comment: Что значит количество вызовов макроса? Во время компиляции макрос будет просто развернут, а во время выполнения вообще вызываться будут функции и ни о каких макросах там нет никакой информации. Если вам все таки нужна какая-то идентификация, просто используйте номер строки `__LINE__`

Comment: И да там есть еще встроенный макрос `__COUNTER__` в [некоторых компиляторах](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html). [Здесь работает например](http://ideone.com/PExwQH)

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите в сторону `BOOST_PP_COUNTER`.

UPD:
Полагаю что boost preprocessor использует только макросы, что удовлетворяет вашим условиям, думаю что не будет проблем использовать его на C99.
Скорее будут проблемы в данном примере.

1. `#include BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER()` никак не включить в макрос изложенный в вопросе.
2. Данный счетчик будет глобальным для всех макросов, на сколько я знаю можно это обойти.
3. Есть весьма скромные ограничения на количество "переменных" (slots) в boost preprocessor.

Возможно вам стоит пересмотреть свою задачу, поскольку она не тривиальна и скорее всего не решаема на макропроцессоре.

Comment: Хотелось бы имитировать такой функционал стандартным С99 и древним компилятором.

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, в С99 таких инструментов, как Вам хочется, нет (по крайней мере мне в контексте с99 термина "переменная препроцессора" точно не попадалось).
Есть вот такой вариант решения этой задачи, хотя он в полном смысле и не соотвествует Вашему требованию, чтобы переменная была "не в коде программы":

```
#define BLOCK(a) printf("This is %d block\n", (a));

void wrap_func(){
  static unsigned int incr_count = 0;
  incr_count++;
  BLOCK(incr_count);
}

#define INCR_BLOCK() wrap_func()   

void main(){
    --- some lines of code --
    INCR_BLOCK();
    --- some lines of code --
    INCR_BLOCK();
    --- some lines of code --
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Эх! Почему бы если уж вы занимаетесь метапрограммированием, не позвать на помощь старую добрую кодогенерацию?

Пишем генератор:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const int max = 1000;
    const char name[] = "VAR";
    const char prefix[] = "This is block No. ";
    const char postfix[] = "";

    FILE* out = fopen("block.h", "w");
    fprintf(out, "#ifndef VAR\n");
    fprintf(out, "#define VAR 0\n");

    for (int val = 0; val < max; val++)
    {
        fprintf(out, "#elif VAR==%d\n", val);
        fprintf(out, "#undef VAR\n");
        fprintf(out, "#define VAR %d\n", val + 1);
    }

    fprintf(out, "#endif\n");
    fprintf(out, "\n");
    fprintf(out, "#define QUOTE(V) #V\n");
    fprintf(out, "#define STRINGIFY(V) QUOTE(V)\n");
    fprintf(out, "puts(\"%s\" STRINGIFY(VAR) \"%s\");\n", prefix, postfix);
    fprintf(out, "#undef STRINGIFY\n");
    fprintf(out, "#undef QUOTE\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Он сгенерирует нам header наподобие такого:

```
#ifndef VAR
#define VAR 0
#elif VAR==0
#undef VAR
#define VAR 1
#elif VAR==1
...
#elif VAR==999
#undef VAR
#define VAR 1000
#endif

#define QUOTE(V) #V
#define STRINGIFY(V) QUOTE(V)
puts("This is block No. " STRINGIFY(VAR) "");
#undef STRINGIFY
#undef QUOTE
```

(Идею с `QUOTE`/`STRINGIFY` утащил из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196093/276994) @jfs).

Теперь можно использовать так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    puts("Before");
    #include "block.h"

    #include "block.h"

    #include "block.h"
    puts("After");

    return 0;
}
```

Выводится:

> Before
>   This is block No. 0
>   This is block No. 1
>   This is block No. 2
>   After

Параметры кодогенератора можно вынести в аргументы командной строки, разумеется. И включить кодогенерацию в проект.

Comment: Жесть, просто жесть. Получился счетчик который вдобавок хранит массив своих значений. Метапрограммирование в C беспощадно.

Comment: @igumnov: Угу, изврат, конечно, знатный.